# Can I pickle Python objects in memory instead of a physical file?

Tags: python, serialization, pickle

I have seen and written code to pickle objects in Python. But they all create physical file to contain data. I want that I write the data in memory and read it and pickle it and transfer it.

Is it even possible ?

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import io
import codecs
import pickle


# Model class to send Process Data to the server
class ProcessData:
 process_id = 0
 project_id = 0
 task_id = 0
 start_time = 0
 end_time = 0
 user_id = 0
 weekend_id = 0

# Model class to send image data to the server
class ProcessScreen:
 process_id = 0
 image_data = bytearray()


image_name = "Dharmindar_screen.jpg"
ImageGrab.grab().save(image_name,"JPEG")

image_data = None
with codecs.open(image_name,'rb') as image_file:
 image_data = image_file.read()



serialized_process_data = io.BytesIO()

process_data = ProcessData()
process_data.process_id = 1
process_data.project_id = 2
process_data.task_id = 3
process_data.user_id = 4
process_data.weekend_id = 5
process_data.start_time = 676876
process_data.end_time = 787987

process_screen = ProcessScreen()
process_screen.process_id = process_data.process_id
process_screen.image_data = image_data


prepared_process_data = (process_data, process_screen)

process_data_serializer = pickle.Pickler()
process_data_serializer(serialized_process_data).dump(prepared_process_data)

print('Data serialized.')


if process_data_serializer is not None:
    d = process_data_serializer.getvalue()
    deserialized_data = None
    with open(d, 'rb') as serialized_data_file:
        process_deserializer = pickle.Unpickler(serialized_data_file)
        deserialized_data = process_deserializer.load()
else:
    print('Empty')
```

The above code throws the TypeError: Required argument 'file' (pos 1) not found

Comment: Do you mean write it to RAM? If you'd like to send the object to some other Python code you could simply pass it as a parameter, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Simply I am willing to send my data through Socket to the server. For that I need to pickle the object. But for that I have seen every code and they say that first write the object in form of bytes to a file and then retreive from that file again. I want to do it in memory instead of physically writting the file.

Comment: Well you could use a StringIO object, which provides the buffer instance, but as Shayn says you should really explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Use [`pickle.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pickle.html#pickle.dumps)?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but why not look at using something like GRPC, in the long run this will likely be more maintainable thttps://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/python.html

Comment: I have found something called byte-like objects. I am exploring it. They are like MemoryView, bytes, bytearray and array.array. The follow the buffer protocol. Pickling is possible on byte-like objects. I am trying to implement it. Lets see if it works and I will post it here as well.

Comment: @Rawing your answer is correct. I was looking for that only. Write it as a separate answer so I will mark it as a correct answer and close the question.

Answer (score 12):

The File object you pass to `pickle.dump` just needs a write method, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle.dump

> file must have a write() method that accepts a single string argument. It can thus be a file object opened for writing, a StringIO object, or any other custom object that meets this interface.

Instead of using a StringIO object, you could even create your own class to store the pickled data, for example

```
class MyFile(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []
    def write(self, stuff):
        self.data.append(stuff)
```

and then just pickle to an instance of this class:

```
class ExampleClass(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.data = x  
a = ExampleClass(123)
f = MyFile()
pickle.dump(a, f)
```

Another option is, as proposed by @rawing, is to use `pickle.dumps` which will directly return a string that you can use, compare [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle.dumps).

Comment: Your method definitely works. But I was looking for something simple and @Rawing commented on the question and suggested that I should be using pickle.dumps instead of pickle .dump and thats very simple to do.